# Blazor Webassembly shows wrong time in UI

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-client-side, blazor-webassembly

I'm developing my app in `.Net 5.0 Blazor WebAssembly`. I'm displaying current time in HTML. But the time displayed is always `-5.30 Hrs` the time displayed in my system clock.

After some googling I found the following in [official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/globalization-localization?view=aspnetcore-5.0#blazor-webassembly).

I added the below tags in `.csproj` file but still no luck.

Here is my code:

**.csproj:**

```xml
<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
    <BlazorWebAssemblyLoadAllGlobalizationData>true</BlazorWebAssemblyLoadAllGlobalizationData>
    <InvariantGlobalization>true</InvariantGlobalization>
    <ServiceWorkerAssetsManifest>service-worker-assets.js</ServiceWorkerAssetsManifest>
</PropertyGroup>

<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly" Version="5.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.DevServer" Version="5.0.0" PrivateAssets="all" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Localization" Version="5.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Net.Http.Json" Version="5.0.0" />
</ItemGroup>
```

**Code:**

```
@using System.Threading
@implements IDisposable

<p>@CurrentDateTime</p>

@code {
    private Timer _timer;
    public string CurrentDateTime { get; set; }

    protected override void OnAfterRender(bool firstRender)
    {
        if (firstRender)
        {
            _timer = new Timer(DateTimeCallback, null, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
        }
    }

    private async void DateTimeCallback(object state)
    {
        CurrentDateTime = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.ToLocalTime().ToString("dd MMM yyyy hh:mm:ss tt");
        await InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _timer?.Dispose();
    }
}
```

**Time Screenshot:**

[image]

Please assist on what I'm missing.

Comment: What do you get without the `ToLocalTime()`? And what timezone is your computer set to?

Comment: Something is defintely wrong. it doesn't appear to be converting UTC back to IST(?)

Comment: `.UtcNow.ToLocalTime()` should just be `.Now` but this code works fine on my pc. I am UTC +11 atm.

Comment: @phuzi my computer is set to `UTC +5.30` Time Zone.  I get the same result for `.Now` or `.Utc.Now` with or without `ToLocalTIme()` and @Brian Parker `.Now` also doesn't seem to work

Comment: Not sure but seems to be a live bug https://github.com/mono/mono/issues/15260

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue got resolved after updating `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly` and `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.DevServer` nuget packages from version `5.0.0` to `5.0.1`